# Page redirect after user logs in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to be able to redirect the user to a different home page immediately after they log in (this part is working) but I would still like a logged in user to be able to access the index feed if they want.  At the moment they can only see favourites_show_path but not  @guidelines = Guideline.order(:title).all.  Is there a way (without having to build a second index action and view) to get home page after login to direct to favourites_show_path but to still be able to see  @guidelines = Guideline.order(:title).all?

```
 def index
    if params[:search].present?
    @search = Sunspot.search(Guideline) do  
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @guidelines = @search.results
  else
    redirect_to favourites_show_path, :action => 'index' and return if current_user
    @guidelines = Guideline.order(:title).all
  end
```

Comment: no. they will always be redirected.  can't you do the redirect on the login action instead?

Comment: I use devise - you are probably right that I should be doing this on another action as I still want the index action to function as it was

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `@guidelines...` out of the condition and rename the search results' symbol:

```
def index
  @guidelines = Guideline.order(:title).all
  if params[:search].present?
    @search = Sunspot.search(Guideline) do  
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @results = @search.results
  else
    redirect_to favourites_show_path, :action => 'index' and return if current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to work.  I'm not sure why the search results symbol needs to be changed.  The point of this is that is that if you've searched then symbol guideline will just be the search results, otherwise symbol guidelines will be all the guidelines.  The way you mentioned will still redirect the user to favourites_show_path if they are logged in and therefore will not allow them to see symbol guidelines (unless they run a search).

Comment: I see. So `@guidelines` is either everything or the search results? And they will be displayed on `favourites_show_path`?

Comment: yes, @guidelines is everything or the search results.  They will be displayed on guidelines_path.  Immediately after login I want it to direct to favourites_show_path (which it currently does) but I would also like a current_user to be able to see guidelines_path (for all guidelines) if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have solved this.  I should have been adding the redirect onto the login action as suggested.  So I've removed

```
redirect_to favourites_show_path, :action => 'index' and return if current_user
```

from my index action and instead added to my application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
favourites_show_path
end
```